# Window title in bottom of Activities overview is not visible when opening multiple windows

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, activities-overview

Ubuntu Dock on Left of screen with no window title:
[image: Ubuntu Dock on Left of screen with no window title]

Ubuntu Dock on Bottom of screen with window title:
[image: Ubuntu Dock on Bottom of screen with window title]

I would like some help in fixing this behavior: with the Ubuntu dock on the left or right of the screen the title of the windows on the bottom of screen is not visible but if I have the dock on the bottom of the screen the window title is visible. I tried searching online for the issue but I didn't know exactly how to search for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You very likely cannot until you have good javascript coding capabilities to change the Ubuntu Dock extension, such that it also changes how the window spread works. Your best chance is to file an issue to the Ubuntu developers, and eventually also to the developer of the Dash to Dock extension, on which Ubuntu Dock is based.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I use the extension "Panel to bottom"  and thus I am also affected by the issue.